# spark-csv or pyspark-csv in Spark environment (IBM Bluemix)

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, pyspark

I need to load a number of large CSV files in Spark on Bluemix.

I can do it via sc.testFile and then map it, but that requires repetitive and cumbersome code.

Is there a way to add/load either databricks spark-csv package, or pyspark-csv to the environment (tried but it didn't like it)?

I saw the example of doing it via pandas, but since some of the files could be very large (10's GB's), it didn't sound like that was a good idea. This is in Python but I could switch to Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Python notebook, you can use

```
sc.addPyFile("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/seahboonsiew/pysparkcsv/master/pyspark_csv.py")
```

to add `pyspark-csv` to your runtime environment. Have a look at the "NY Motor Vehicle Accidents Analysis" sample notebook, in which we added `pyspark-csv`.

In a Scala notebook, you can use

```
%AddDeps com.databricks spark-csv_2.10 1.3.0 --transitive`
```

to add `spark-csv`. Of course, you can choose a different version.

What do you mean by "(tried but it didn't like it)?" ?

Loading large amount of data into a `pandas.DataFrame` is not a good idea, you are right.

Comment: Need to go back, retried the pyspark last night (even before I saw the response) and got it to work - so not sure what I must have typo'd.  For  spark-csv tried to reference it complained that it couldn't get to com.databricks, when I added the 2.10 jar I ended up with a JVM stack dump (which I only cursorly looked at, it showed it had the jar and I didn't get the stack dump on local when processing the same file - so switched to pyspark).  Will go back and test spark-csv later